# Inject String Value from property file into a set

Tags: java, spring

I have a string in my property file

> set.test=FIRST,SECOND,THIRD,THIRD

I want to inject this into a set using @Value

```
@Value(value = "${set.test}")
private Set<String> testSet;
```

Is there a way for spring to split it based on comma and load it into the set automatically or should I assign it to an array and convert it to Set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous answer is very close, here is what works for me:

```
@Value("#{'${set.test}'.split(',')}")
```